# Change keys for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an json array that I've decoded that looks like:

```
[d] =>
    [Current Markets] => [0] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 8
                             => [RaceNumber] => 02
                             => [StartingPrice] => $2
                             => [GameName] => something
                      => [1] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 2
                             => [RaceNumber] => 01
                             => [StartingPrice] => $1.5
                             => [GameName] => something
                      => [2] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 9
                             => [RaceNumber] => 03 
                             => [StartingPrice] => $9
                             => [GameName] => something
                      => [3] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 1
                             => [RaceNumber] => 03
                             => [StartingPrice] => $3.5
                             => [GameName] => something
                      => [4] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 4
                             => [RaceNumber] => 02
                             => [StartingPrice] => $2.25
                             => [GameName] => something
                      => [5] => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                             => [RunnerNumber] => 4
                             => [RaceNumber] => 01
                             => [StartingPrice] => $1.25
                             => [GameName] => something
```

Now, I don't know how many races there could be, or how many runners there may be per race, but I need to be able to sort it by MarketNumber then race number, THEN by runner number within that race.

eg:

```
(MarketNumber)54321 => (RaceNumber)01 => (RunnerNumber)2 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 2
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 01
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $1.5
                                                         => [GameName] => something
                                      => (RunnerNumber)4 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 4
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 01
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $1.25
                                                         => [GameName] => something
                       (RaceNumber)02 => (RunnerNumber)4 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 4
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 02
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $2.25
                                                         => [GameName] => something
                                      => (RunnerNumber)8 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 8
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 02
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $2
                                                         => [GameName] => something
                       (RaceNumber)03 => (RunnerNumber)1 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 1
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 03
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $3.5
                                                         => [GameName] => something
                                      => (RunnerNumber)1 => [MarketNumber] => 54321
                                                         => [RunnerNumber] => 9
                                                         => [RaceNumber] => 03 
                                                         => [StartingPrice] => $9
                                                         => [GameName] => something
```

I've tried array_merge_recursive, but it didn't seem to do anything, I've tried ksort(), and asort(), but it didn't sort it correctly, even with flags.

Right now, I'm at:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
            $end = array($array['DisplayNumber'] => $array);
            $list = array($array => $end);
            print_r($list);
        }
```

While it sorts it great, I don't seem to be able to get it to have a key then the array etc like:

```
[MarketNumber] => [RaceNumber01] => [RunnerNumber1] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber2] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber3] => OtherStuff
               => [RaceNumber02] => [RunnerNumber1] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber2] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber3] => OtherStuff
               => [RaceNumber03] => [RunnerNumber1] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber2] => OtherStuff
                                 => [RunnerNumber3] => OtherStuff
```

I think it may be to do with the fact that it's a foreach loop, but I can't figure out how to change that, because it only then shows the very last iteration.

Comment: How is the JSON array itself being generated?

Comment: From a different program that outputs it. unfortunately I can't change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a magic function that'll do this for you, but it's pretty simple to just build your own loop that'll handle it.

Basically, we're just looping through the inputs, and inserting each item in the appropriate place in the results array, creating any intermediate arrays as needed.

Something like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input['d']['Current Markets'] as $item) {
    $market = $item['MarketNumber'];
    $race = $item['RaceNumber'];
    $runner = $item['RunnerNumber'];
    if (!isset($output[$market])) $output[$market] = array();
    if (!isset($output[$market][$race])) $output[$market][$race]= array();
    $output[$market][$race][$runner] = $item;
}
```

I'm not sure if you just want to group the data - which the above code handles - or actually sort it as well. If you do want to sort it, we'll just need to loop through each group at the end and use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort), like this:

```
foreach ($output as $market => $marketGroup) {
    foreach ($output[$market] as $race => $raceGroup) {
        ksort($output[$market][$race]); // sort race group by runner
    }
    ksort($output[$market]); // sort market group by race
}
ksort($output); // sort overall data by market
```

Comment: I just realised that it doesn't actually sort the race numbers, so it still ends up being something like race 7, then race 5, then race 10 etc etc... any ideas?

Comment: @Kozbot see my updated answer, where I added a section to handle sorting to the end.

Comment: It's really strange, because I can see what you're doing, but the code just doesn't work for me. $race was always sorted from smallest to largest, but $market won't budge. :(

Comment: What's the actual data that you're sorting? Your example only shows a single market. It may help to add a `SORT_NUMERIC` flag as the second parameter to the `ksort()` calls.

Comment: The race number actually comes up as 'Race 01', 'Race 02' etc... I'd striped 'Race 0' from each one, but still nothing, then, I thought I'd leave the 0 in, but didn't work, and I just tried leaving it all, but still nothing. I've tried SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, and even ARRAY_MULTISORT, but no dice... lol I seriously can't figure out why.

Comment: @Kozbot If you add the actual JSON data to your question (or at least a sample that illustrates the problem), I'll investigate further.

Comment: Thanks jcsanyi. I've added the code here: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73509372/racecard_2013-11-18_Flamingo_Park.txt)

Comment: @Kozbot What are the actual fields that you're using for each of the values? I'm assuming you're using MarketID, MarketName, and DisplayNumber - but let me know if that's not right. What I'm seeing so far is that each race has a different MarketID - so because they're sorted by MarketID first, the races themselves appear to be out of order.

Comment: I'm using GameID which is MarketNumber, MarketName for RaceNumber and DisplayNumber for horseNumber. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: OK! I just did it (out of sheer luck I might add)... I added:     `$raceNo = str_replace('Race 0', '', $race);` after the  `if(!isset($output[$market][$race]))` and it worked! Who'd have thought! Thank you again for all your help!